# Understanding makefile generated by rpcgen

Tags: c, makefile, rpc

1) I am unable to understand the lines 14, 15, 29-37. What do they mean?

2) Also the file "dir.h" generated by line 27 is included in rls_clnt.c and rls_svc.c. Do I need to specify "dir.h" on lines 5 and 7?

```
  1 CLIENT = dir_client
  2 SERVER = dir_server
  3 
  4 SOURCES_CLNT.c = rls_clnt.c
  5 SOURCES_CLNT.h =
  6 SOURCES_SVC.c = rls_svc.c
  7 SOURCES_SVC.h =
  8 SOURCES.x = dir.x
  9 
 10 TARGETS_SVC.c = dir_svc.c   dir_xdr.c
 11 TARGETS_CLNT.c = dir_clnt.c   dir_xdr.c
 12 TARGETS = dir.h dir_xdr.c dir_clnt.c dir_svc.c
 13 
 14 OBJECTS_CLNT = $(SOURCES_CLNT.c:%.c=%.o) $(TARGETS_CLNT.c:%.c=%.o)
 15 OBJECTS_SVC = $(SOURCES_SVC.c:%.c=%.o) $(TARGETS_SVC.c:%.c=%.o)
 16 # Compiler flags 
 17 
 18 CFLAGS += -g
 19 LDLIBS += -lnsl
 20 RPCGENFLAGS =
 21 
 22 # Targets 
 23 
 24 all : $(CLIENT) $(SERVER)
 25 
 26 $(TARGETS) : $(SOURCES.x)
 27     rpcgen $(RPCGENFLAGS) $(SOURCES.x)
 28 
 29 $(OBJECTS_CLNT) : $(SOURCES_CLNT.c) $(SOURCES_CLNT.h) $(TARGETS_CLNT.c)
 30 
 31 $(OBJECTS_SVC) : $(SOURCES_SVC.c) $(SOURCES_SVC.h) $(TARGETS_SVC.c)
 32 
 33 $(CLIENT) : $(OBJECTS_CLNT)
 34     $(LINK.c) -o $(CLIENT) $(OBJECTS_CLNT) $(LDLIBS) 
 35 
 36 $(SERVER) : $(OBJECTS_SVC)
 37     $(LINK.c) -o $(SERVER) $(OBJECTS_SVC) $(LDLIBS)
 38 
 39  clean:
 40      $(RM) core $(TARGETS) $(OBJECTS_CLNT) $(OBJECTS_SVC) $(CLIENT) $(SERVER)
```

~

Comment: Lines 14-15 use [substitution references](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html). Regarding `dir.h` - I think you should include it, otherwise `make` will have no way of knowing that it needs to recompile `rls_clnt.c` if `dir.h` changes.

Comment: I read it and I am not sure I understand it. Does substituting .c with .o 'generates' .o files? Is it like renaming file name from .c to .o? Or is it really using C compiler to generate .o files? If generating .o files is the goal, why not make another rule with a recipe using cc compiler with appropriate flag? Is this like using implicit rules instead of explicit rules?

Comment: No, it's actually a simple string manipulation. If there is a `HELLO` variable containing `hi.c foo.c`, then `$(HELLO)` will yield exactly it. However, if you write `$(HELLO:%.c=%.o)`, then the value will be tokenized and `.c` suffixes will be replaced with `.o`, resulting in `hi.o foo.o`. So, basically line 14 is equal to `OBJECTS_CLNT = rls_clnt.o dir_clnt.o dir_xdr.o`

Comment: But generating .o files(object code) is a compiler's job isn't it? How is just renaming the .c file to .o will generate object code?

Comment: Yes, it's a compiler's job. Lines 14-15 do not do _anything_ with files at all, it's plain variable assignments. These variables are used later to write add dependencies, e.g. on line 29 `$(OBJECTS_CLNT)` is expanded into a list of names of object files, so Make now knows that all these object files depend on the right part of line 29.

Comment: So that must be an implicit rule or predefined recipes if Make figures out that it needs to compile .c files with appropriate flag in order to generate .o files, right?

Comment: Yup, there are [few](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_10.html#SEC95)